# WordPress : Need to change text color from a PHP file

Tags: php, css, wordpress, web

I have this PHP file with the folloing code:

```
<div class="post hentry ivycat-post">
<!-- This is the output of the post TITLE -->
<h2 class="entry-title">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> <------Click Here </a>
</h2>
```

What I need is to change the color of the text that says "Click Here". I'm building a website in wordpress and through other options can't change that text color, neither through CSS.

Thank you.

Comment: Why you can't change it with css?

Comment: You could just change your stylesheet... Or ugly but simple: add `style="color: #00ff00;` to your `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap the text inside a span with class.

```
<div class="post hentry ivycat-post">
<!-- This is the output of the post TITLE -->
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> <span class="clickhere"><------Click Here</span></a></h2>
```

CSS:

```
.clickhere {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow @BodyvolutiomGym :-)

Kindly search stack overflow to see if question is answered already to avoid getting your question down voted.

Just wrap the text you want to change color of in `<span>` and set `color` in `style` attribute.

```
<span style="color:red">Click Here</span>
```

Your entire code looks like this...

```
<div class="post hentry ivycat-post">
<!-- This is the output of the post TITLE -->
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> <------<span style="color:red">Click Here</span> </a></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the color by using [a:link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp) selector in CSS.

```
a:link {
    color: red;
}
```

This will affect the whole website, though. You can restrict the effect for a single link by either using a class or an ID.

```
/* This will only affect links with class "nice" */
a.nice:link {
    color: green;
}

/* This will only affect a single link (as IDs must be unique) with ID "awesome" */
a#awesome:link {
    color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.ivycat-post h2.entry-title a{color:#DDD;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use like thsis

```
<div class="post hentry ivycat-post">
<!-- This is the output of the post TITLE -->
<h2 class="entry-title">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> <------<span style="color:red">Click Here</span> </a>
</h2>
```